# Cannot convert float to UnityEngine.Vector2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do a playermovement script (in the water), but I don't understand how adding forces works.
I want my player to move freely in the environment, like there is no gravity, and I want my player to move slowly upwards than downwards.

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerMovementWater : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody2D rb2;
    public int movementhorizontal = 10;
    public int movementverticalup = 5;
    public int movementverticaldown = 13;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float xdirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float ydirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (xdirection == -1)
        {
            rb2.AddForce(-movementhorizontal * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
        }

        else if (xdirection == 1)
        {
            rb2.AddForce(movementhorizontal * Time.deltaTime; 0f);
        }

        if (ydirection == -1)
        {
            rb2.AddForce(0f, -movementverticaldown * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else if (ydirection == -1)
        {
            rb2.AddForce(0f, movementverticalup * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Try `rb2.AddForce(new Vector2(-movementhorizontal * Time.deltaTime, 0f));`. Btw,, you have a semicolon when calling `AddForce` instead of a comma in the case `xdirection == 1`.

Comment: Wow ! It works.  Thanks a lot dude ! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a vector to use in AddForce, instead of passing 2 parameters.

For example:

```
rb2.AddForce(new Vector2(-movementhorizontal * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
```